# Unable to reference .Net DLL in aspx script

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dll

I have created a fairly standard .Net DLL which I am trying to use in an aspx script, but so far I have not had much luck. The script looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="IncsRoot.IncsSpace" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="IncsAssm" %>
<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim incs As IncsClass
        Dim cs As String
        Dim db As String

        cs = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=HP\SQLEXPRESS;UID=sa;PWD=angela;"
        db = "Vanguard"

        incs = New IncsClass(cs, db)
        incs.show("SELECT category FROM " & db & ".dbo.categories ORDER BY category")
    End Sub
</script>
```

When I try to view this in my browser, I get a parser error on the Assembly directive, saying that Incs cannot be found. Without this directive I get a compilation error, as one might expect. But the DLL has been added to the web site as a reference, which caused it to be copied to a bin directory, and the whole thing compiles OK with VS Express 2013 for Web.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fully qualified name such as `MyProject.MyAssembly`